# How to handle dark mode in Delphi iOS apps

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio, ios-darkmode

When the iPhone is in dark mode, my Delphi 10.3.3 app renders half the TLabel TListBox texts in regular black and the other half in an extremely light gray (almost unreadable).

What must be done to make Firemonkey components work well with iOS dark mode?

Comment: I actually though delphi would recognize your iOS is in dark mode and handle all that automatically ... so this doens't work ?

Comment: In my case, it sometimes works but it often works incorrectly.

Comment: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27620

Comment: I'm now using Delphi 11.3 patch 1 and Xcode 14.3. 

 I've added the key pair Appearance | Light to the project's info.plist.

The project is still being visually mangled to an unusable state when the iPad is in dark mode.

Comment: Adding this key pair to the Info.plist.templateiOS.xml file worked to keep the FMX app in light mode:

<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>

Thanks to Dave Nottage for pointing that out.